# How to Handle Memory Leak Issues Due to INotifyPropertyChanged Events?

Tags: c#, mvvm, memory-leaks, uwp, loose-coupling

I have been working on a project with UWP and it has a lot of INotifyPropertyChanged events attached to a lot of properties. Now what happens is that when I navigate from page to page it causes a huge fluctuation in memory, in the diagnostic tool thing.

To avoid that I have used two things,

Enabled `NavigationCacheMode` in the xaml files in which data are populated,
Implemented `OnNavigatedFrom` function in cs files of views which are related to navigation, inside which there is a `GC.Collect()` call,  which helps take down the  unmanaged memories.

However, as there are just too many INotifyPropertyChanged event handlers in my code, which I am not sure how to get rid of, probably can't , when I navigate between two pages fast,  the memory keeps  rising but when I stop  the navigating frenzy, the memory usage drops down.

I have read that IWeakEventListener/Manager, INotifyPropertyManager can help avoid the memory leak issues for this type of things but I am yet to find any information for UWP , MVVM,

Can someone please give me any resource or guidance as to how I can go about solving the memory leak problem that comes from INotifyPropertyChanged events.

Here's the code for my INotificationBase.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MVVM
{
    public abstract class INotificationBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

        }

         protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, 
 [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

            storage = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            return true;
        }
    }
 }
```

Thank you.

New to UWP, new to MVVM.

Comment: You need to unsubscribe from INotifyPropertyChanged too. Make your classes implement IDisposable, and remove the subscriptions there, and dispose of your objects. Of course much easier said than done if you didn't plan ahead to do this.

Comment: Do you have any Two-Way bindings?  Make sure your property setters check if the value has changed first before firing OnPropertyChanged.

Comment: Hi Sean, I have hardly any Two-Way Bindings, and I am  adding code I am using for setting properties.  It checks whether it is equal to the original value before firing NotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: You can try to use the the Visual Studio tool: Debug=>Profiler=>Performance Profiler and select the Memory Usage checkbox to investigate application memory to find the memory leaks issue. If you still don't know how to resolve the issue, please try to create a simple repro sample to help me view it.